# don't understand some code from a RailsCast tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I watched the RailCasts tutorial #274 on Remember Me and Reset Password.  The code he adds is the following inside `user.rb`

```
def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  save!
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

Here what I don't understand is why the `save!` call inside `send_password_reset`?  Also, I'm not familiar with the syntax in `generate_token`: `self[column]=`. Is this the way to set a column inside a database table?

Here's the `create` action of the `password_resets_controller`

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`save!` saves the object and raises an exception if it fails.

---

`self[column]=`, is a slight meta-programming.

Usually, when you know the column name, you'd do: `self.password_reset_token=`. Which is the same as `self[:password_reset_token]=` or `self["password_reset_token"]=`.

So it's easy to abstract it a bit passing column name as string/symbol.

Clearer?

Answer (score 1):

1) `save!` is like `save`, but raise a `RecordInvalid` exception instead of returning `false` if the record is not valid.

Example from my console:

```
User.new().save  # => false 
User.new().save! # ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank,  Email can't be blank
```

2) `self[column]=` there for setting users column.